# Rpm in stepping motors

Tags: stepper-motor, servo, rpm

Can rpm be in decimals like 2.45 rpm in stepper motors? And is it possible in servo motors?
Can stepping motors be used in closed loop system?

Comment: Why would you think you can't have decimal values for rpm? Though with thinks like car engines, the values are usually in the thousands so the decimal places are pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: But the question was for normal stepper motors..

Comment: Then think of the minute hand on an analogue clock. How many rpm does that do?

Comment: Also: think about **how** a stepper motor is used, how is it controlled? What do you need to make it rotate once. So what is then needed to make it rotate at the rate you want?

Comment: This is a weird question. Can I ask about the motivation?

Answer (score 2):

Stepper motors have no lower limit on how fast you can turn them. Consider one step per day, with 64 steps per rev. That's 1/(64*24*60) or roughly 0.00001 rpm.

Servo motors can turn down to any speed at which you can sense the position and control them.

You *can* run a stepper closed loop, but there are several reasons why people usually don't. It's more difficult to drive a stepper than a servo motor, it's less efficient, and usually slower and less torque than a similar weight servo. The whole point of a stepper is that you can run them open loop, and know they'll go to where you asked. If you pay to close a loop round them, then you're throwing away their one good point.